# Substitute certain characters but not the one found in matches

Tags: search, vim, pattern-matching

Yesterday I tried to substitute all `(` `)` in my text but not the one found in matches from a previous search. I couldn't find a good solution. I did it changing one by one.

*This is my original text*:

```
(Peter Jackson) is the man who..... (John Johnson) is the man who....  
and (John Johnson) is also the man who.. not as (Jon Johnson)
more (letters) etc.
```

My search pattern: **`/(\a*\sJohnson)`**
How can I substitute all `(` `)` characters in the text to `[` `]`, but not the one found in matches?

*The result should be:*

```
[Peter Jackson] is the man who..... (John Johnson) is the man who....  
and (John Johnson) is also the man who.. not as (Jon Johnson)
more [letters] etc.
```

**Edit**
Is there an easy method to substitute one or more whatever characters in a text but not these in matches?

Comment: I've edited your question. Is it what you mean?

Comment: You did well. Yes that is what I mean. I would like to find a (general) way for the next time to do it faster as what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the following substitution command to achieve the purpose in
question.

```
:%s/(\(.\{-}\%(IGNORE.\{-}\)\@<!\))/[\1]/g
```

where `IGNORE` designates the pattern that does not match in parentheses that
are to change (`\a*\sJohnson`, for instance).

In order to solve a general problem of substituting everywhere in buffer
except in the matches of `IGNORE` pattern, one can use the command

```
:%s/\(IGNORE\)\zs\|s/\=submatch(1)!=''?'':'t'/g
```

Comment: ib, if `\a*\sJohnson` is my search and I want to substitute all characters in the text to spaces sauf `\a*\sJohnson` or I want to change all `s` in the text to 't` sauf the `s` in matches, what would be the regex?

Comment: @Remonn:  Take a look at the updated answer.  If the command I have added solve the problem (I am not sure that I got it right), I will elaborate the description.

Comment: ib, Thank you. I tried you code without success. Fill p.e. 3 lines with the character `a` and put the word `try` inside the lines (the ignore text) and try to substitute all `r` with `b`. I can't make it work. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @Remonn:  In that case, command should be `:%s/\(try\)\zs\|r/\=submatch(1)!=''?'':'b'/g`.  For the example you describe (words `try` surrounded by letters `a`), it does not change text, since all occurrences of `r` are inside matches of the ignore pattern, `try`.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work in a vimscript when it works in the command line? This is my vimscript code: `exe '9s/\%V\(try\)\zs\|a\%V/\=submatch(1)!=""?"":"b"/g'`

Comment: and why does my visual block moves one character to the left if I execute `:%s/\%V\(try\)\zs\|a\%V/\=submatch(1)!=""?"":"b"/g` in the command line?

Comment: @Remonn:  If you want to limit the scope of the substitution with visual selection, insert the `\%V` specifier *immediately before* atoms matching the *first* and the *last* character of the text to replace.  For instance, in order to use this technique to substitute all occurrences of `don` inside visual selection ignoring those matching in `london`, run `:'<,'>s/\(london\)\zs\|\%Vdo\%Vn/\=submatch(1)!=''?'':'grandee'/g`.  In case of single-character substitution pattern, only one `\%V` is necessary: `:'<,'>s/\(london\)\zs\|\%Vn/\=submatch(1)!=''?'':'m'/g`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\@!`([Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
:%s/(\%(\a*\sJohnson\)\@!\([^)]*\))/[\1]/g
     ->|............|<---
```

- `\%(...\)\@!` is a `Negative Lookahead`.
- `\([^)]*\)` will match everything except `)`.
- I use `\%(` to ignore a captured group, otherwise you need `/[\2]/`

Comment: Nice this would be much easier as what I did, but how would you p.e. subsitute all "s" in a text but not the one found in matches?

Answer (score 2):

This can work:

```
:%s/(\(\a*\sJohnson\))/LEFTPARENT\1RIGHTPARENT/g
:%s/(/[/g
:%s/)/]/g
:%s/LEFTPARENT/(/g
:%s/RIGHTPARENT/)/g
```